# Datatable column width issue after "refresh" row data

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables, material-design

I'm currently using datatable to produce table below:

[image]

I'm happy with the result as the width of each column is calculated automatically, resulting 1 line per row, looks awesome. The table above is generated via API, by using simple code below:

```
var dataTable;

// This is the button with text "Filter" as shown in screenshot
$('#search').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (dataTable) {
        dataTable.clear();
        dataTable.destroy();
    }

    $.ajax({ 
        type : "GET", 
        url : contextPath + "/api/company/list", 
        contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8", 
        data : { token : token(), name: $('#name').val() }, 
        success : function(data) {
            if (data) {
                var tag = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var c = data[i];

                    tag += '<tr>' 
                        + '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>' 
                        + '<td>' + c.name + '</td>' 
                        + '<td>' + c.registrationNumber + '</td>' 
                        + '<td>' + c.createdTime + '</td>'
                        + '<td>'
                        + ' <a href="' + contextPath + '/company?id=' + c.id + '" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search text-info"></i></a>'
                        + ' <a href="' + contextPath + '/company/update?id=' + c.id + '"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit text-warning"></i></a>' 
                        + '</td>'
                        + '</tr>';
                }

                $('#tableBody').html(tag);
                dataTable = $('#tableBody').parent().DataTable();
            } else {
                alert("Oops, there's an error! Please reload the page");
            }
        }, error : function(xhr) {
            alert("Oops, there's an error! Please reload the page");
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
});
```

Snippet of table html:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table data-table">
            <thead class=" text-primary">
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Registration Number</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, problem arise when I click the filter button and re-run the same onClick function, the table column will be somehow resize and looks below:

[image]

The width of each column is resized resulting 3 lines per row, subsequent clicks on Filter button will remain in this format. Anybody know how to avoid this column width recalculation thing?

Comment: can you give working example of it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently this happens because datatables assign the width attribute to all th.

Adding the autoWidth false property prevents that.

```
$('#tableBody').parent().DataTable({"autoWidth": false});
```

And the width calculation is then automated by web browser (eg chrome)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "autoWidth": false, // might need this
  "columns": [
    { "width": "20%" },
    null, // automatically calculates
    null  // remaining width
  ]
} );
```